# {{ !$last && ', ' || '.'}} is this working as ternary operator or if-else condition

Tags: angularjs

I am developing an application using AngularJS. I have used the `if-else` conditions and ternary Operator. Once I found a code `{{ !$last && ', ' || '.'}}` to put the `,` after each entry and `.` at the end. It is working fine, but I have a confusion about its working process. Is it working like an `if-else` condition or ternary operator? My whole example is as below.

```
<span data-ng-repeat="allSuppliers in vm.allIncentiveSuppliers | unique:'supplierName'">
    {{allSuppliers.supplierName }}{{ !$last && ', ' || '.'}}
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a form of ternary operator. `&&` returns first operand if it is a falsy value and second operand if first operand is truthy e.g. `1 && 3` will return `3` but `0 && 3` will return `0`. Second operator is not evaluated if first is falsy. `||` is similar but returns first operand if it is truthy and second operand if first is falsy.

So basically `cond && val1 || val2` is equivalend to `cond ? val1 : val2` under condition that `val1` is truthy value. If this is not the case e.g. `cond && 0 || 1` this will always return last value `1` in this case.

For readability reasons you should always prefer ternary opreator `?:` than boolean shortcircuting operators.

Comment: Can we use the same method in all technologies?

Comment: Means in all languages like C,PHP etc.. As per Ven's answer I got it.

Comment: @HarshGupta It will not work in C, C++, C# and Java. Don't know about PHP. But is will be bad practice, all of these languages support `?:` operator, that will do exactly the same but in almost every of language.

Comment: `||` and `&&` should be primary used to evaluate boolean expressions, sometimes their short-circuit property is handy e.g. `if (foo && doSth())` but generally you should use `if()` and `?:` to express application logic.

Answer (score 0):

Be wary that this won't work in languages where `&&` only return a boolean value, like C and PHP. There, `3 && 4` returns `1`/`true`, so your code won't work as expected.

In JS, `&&` returns the first truthy value or `false`. So `3 && 4` returns `3` and your code works fine.

Another thing to be careful of is when you want `&&`'s right-hand-side to be falsy:

`cond() && false || true` will **always** return true.

Answer (score 0):

A ternary operator is basically a shorthand for if-else condition. So the syntax you provided can be termed as both.

Other varients of that expression can be:

```
{{ !$last ? ', ' : '.'}}
```

Or

```
{{ $last ? '.' : ','}}
```